# Slicing out a specific from a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, slice

I have one list and I want to print out all elements of it but skip one specific.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to print out:

```
1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

(in a column like a regular for-loop)

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to skip a certain element or index?

Answer (score 2):

Just slice on both sides and concatenate:

```py
def skip_over(lst, i):
    return lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]

skip_over([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1) # [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you want to skip over all occurrences of a value, filter with a list comprehension:

```py
def skip_all(lst, v):
    return [x for x in lst if x != v]

skip_all([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5], 2) # [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you want to skip over the first occurrence of a value, then use `index` to get its index:

```py
def skip_first(lst, v):
    try:
        i = lst.index(v)
    except ValueError:
        # value not in list so return whole thing
        return lst
    return lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]

skip_first([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5], 2) # [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you specify the element to be skipped by its *position (index):*

   ```
   for position, element in enumerate(a):
       if position != specified_position:
           print(element)
   ```
2. If you specify the element to be skipped by its *value:*

   ```
   for element in a:
       if element != specified_value:
           print(element)
   ```